# Using variables in sed -f (where sed script is in a file rather than inline)

Tags: sed

We have a process which can use a file containing `sed` commands to alter piped input.

I need to replace a placeholder in the input with a variable value, e.g. in a single `-e` type of command I can run;

```
$ echo "Today is XX" | sed -e "s/XX/$(date +%F)/"
Today is 2012-10-11
```

However I can only specify the `sed` aspects in a file (and then point the process at the file), E.g. a file called `replacements.sed` might contain;

```
s/XX/Thursday/
```

So obviously;

```
$ echo "Today is XX" | sed -f replacements.sed
Today is Thursday
```

If I want to use an environment variable or shell value, though, I can't find a way to make it expand, e.g. if `replacements.txt` contains;

```
s/XX/$(date +%F)/
```

Then;

```
$ echo "Today is XX" | sed -f replacements.sed
Today is $(date +%F)
```

Including double quotes in the text of the file just prints the double quotes.

Does anyone know a way to be able to use variables in a `sed` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<\! > replacements.sed
/XX/{s//'"$(date +%F)"'/;s/.*/echo '&'/e}
!
echo "Today is XX" | sed -f replacements.sed
```

If you don't have GNU sed, try:

```
cat <<\! > replacements.sed
/XX/{
    s//'"$(date +%F)"'/
    s/.*/echo '&'/
}
!
echo "Today is XX" | sed -f replacements.sed | sh
```

Comment: Genius - I don't understand it but it works! (I'm using the GNU sed version).

Comment: This is very clever indeed, though it requires that you regenerate your script for every use.

Comment: @ghoti the `replacement.sed` contains the literal `'"$(date +%F"'` it is only when the script is run and the shell invoked either by the flag `e` or by being piped through to the shell `| sh` that the date is interpolated via the `echo` command.

Comment: Ah, right.  For your non-GNU suggestion, you might want to add a semicolon before the `}`.

Comment: To add a newline in the replacement expression using a sed file, what finally worked for me is escaping a literal newline. Example: to append a newline after the string NewLineHere, then this worked for me, but the _ is actually a literal newline bc SO comments do not allow blank lines lol: `s/NewLineHere/NewLineHere\ `_`/g`. I posted this as an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, it's not possible. Your best bet will be :

**INPUT FILE**

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

**SH SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/sh

STRING="${1//\//\\/}"   # using parameter expansion to prevent / collisions

shift

sed "
s/aaa/$STRING/
" "$@"
```

**COMMAND LINE**

```
./sed.sh "fo/obar" <file path>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
fo/obar
bbb
ccc
```

Comment: Note that this fails if `$STRING` contains your delimiter (a `/` for example.)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can't use variables in a sed script, but you might be able to "fake" it using extra leading input that gets added to your hold buffer.  For example:

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ cat scr.sed 
1{;h;d;};/^--$/g
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ sed -f scr.sed <(date '+%Y-%m-%d'; printf 'foo\n--\nbar\n')
foo
2012-10-10
bar
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$
```

In this example, I'm using process redirection to get input into sed.  The "important" data is generated by `printf`.  You could cat a file instead, or run some other program.  The "variable" is produced by the `date` command, and becomes the first line of input to the script.

The sed script takes the first line, puts it in sed's hold buffer, then deletes the line.  Then for any subsequent line, if it matches a double dash (our "macro replacement"), it substitutes the contents of the hold buffer.  And prints, because that's sed's default action.

Hold buffers (g, G, h, H and x commands) represent "advanced" sed programming.  But once you understand how they work, they open up new dimensions of sed fu.

Note: This solution only helps you replace entire lines.  Replacing substrings within lines may be possible using the hold buffer, but I can't imagine a way to do it.

(Another note: I'm doing this in FreeBSD, which uses a different sed from what you'll find in Linux.  This may work in GNU sed, or it may not; I haven't tested.)

Answer (score 0):

I am in agreement with sputnick.  I don't believe that sed would be able to complete that task.

However, you could generate that file on the fly.

You could change the date to a fixed string, like
 `__DAYOFWEEK__`.

Create a temp file, use sed to replace `__DAYOFWEEK__` with `$(date +%Y)`.

Then parse your file with `sed -f $TEMPFILE`.

sed is great, but it might be time to use something like perl that can generate the date on the fly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had a perl version working (the solution could be a perl or sed file) but the data is piped into the command from a cat of a file that can have c500k records. This was taking 40mins+ with a simple perl script so I wanted a quicker solution which I was hoping sed might provide.

Answer (score 0):

To add a newline in the replacement expression using a sed file, what finally worked for me is escaping a literal newline. Example: to append a newline after the string NewLineHere, then this worked for me:

```
#! /usr/bin/sed -f
s/NewLineHere/NewLineHere\
/g
```

Not sure it matters but I am on Solaris unix, so not GNU sed for sure.